# bash variable substitution to remove the start [ and final ]

Tags: bash

I am using substitution to remove the start `[` and final `]` from strings such as "[abc]" as follows.

```
braces="]["
letter="[abc]"
ltr="${letter//[$braces]/}"
```

But the substitution fails for the string `letter=[[:digit:]]`.  I want the substitution to only remove the outer enclosing `[]`, rather than removing all occurrences.

Comment: You have to do it in two steps, you can only remove one, all, first, or the last occurrence, but not and.

Comment: Uum, regex allows `[][]` to mach `]` and `[`. The `]` right after the first `[` is a special exception, and the `[` after that is of course allowed because it’s not `]`.

Comment: in any case, you should also look into `${var#[}` and `${var%]}`